# Hibernate: sorting on an Embeddable field is not sorting for all multiple fields in an embeddable field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hql

Hibernate: sorting on an Embeddable field is not sorting for multiple fields in an embeddable

Entity class

```
@Entity(name = "s.mainEntity")
  @Table(name = "Main_Entity"
  Public class MainEntity{
  
  @Embedded
  @NotNull
  private CurrencyAmount cost;
  
  ....
  }
```

Embeddable field

```
@Embeddable
public class CurrencyAmount implements Comparable<CurrencyAmount>, Serializable {

  @Column(nullable = false, precision = 20, scale = 6)
  private BigDecimal amount;

  @Column(name = "currency_code", nullable = false, length = 3)
  private String currencyCode;
  
  }
```

HQL query with sorting on cost field

```
 ..... generatedAlias1 order by generatedAlias0.cost desc, generatedAlias0._id desc
```

Translated sql query

```
 WHERE main.uuid=?
ORDER BY main.amount,
         main.currency_code DESC,
         main.id DESC
LIMIT ?
```

From the above sql query, the amount always sorts amount by ASC because the hibernate adds the sorting DESC only to the last param and not for all params.

But my expectation is to get

```
ORDER BY main.amount DESC, main.currency_code DESC, main.id DESC
```

Does someone know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following order by clause:

```
...
order by
  generatedAlias0.cost.amount desc,
  generatedAlias0.cost.currencyCode desc,
  generatedAlias0._id desc
```